# Regex to extract (german) street number

Tags: regex

I have the following street constellations:

```
|               Street name               | extracted value |
| --------------------------------------- | --------------- |
| Lilienstr. 12a                          | 12a             |
| Hagentorwall 3                          | 3               |
| Seilerstr. 14 (Eingang Birkenstr.)      | 14              |
| Guentherstr. 43 B                       | 43 B            |
| Eberhard-Leibnitz Str. 1 WH 5B 241      | 1               |
| 1019-1781 Borderlinx C/O SEKO Logistics |        -        |
```

My `Regex` is partially working (https://regex101.com/r/KumamP/2):

```
\d+(?:[a-zA-Z]$|\s[a-zA-Z]$)?
```

Someone has got a better solution for me? `Eberhard-Leibnitz Str.` should only give me one result or none. `1019-1781 Borderlinx C/O SEKO Logistics` should give me none result.

Comment: `1019-1781 Borderlinx C/O SEKO Logistics` is *not* a German address line.

Comment: some additional information on german street numbers (and their format limitations) would be useful

Comment: It is too tricky, if the address can occur in unknown contexts, there is no safe way to identify them. Also, see [this attempt](https://regex101.com/r/KumamP/3).

Comment: Furthermore, in Berlin we have (a couple!) of streets named like `Straße 123` because there has no name been assigned to them yet: https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassenverzeichnis/S. The address would be `Straße 123 1` in  that case.

Comment: And in Berlin there is the famous "Strasse des 17. Juni", where you can have an address like "Strasse des 17. Juni 135", which will break your regex. If you check out Mannheim, there are "streets" like "A1, 2-3" (see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratestadt) 
To make a long story short, if you want to get reliable results, you have to parse and compare with official street listings.

Comment: What I want to say is, that you can only make assumptions. Ideally you ask your users to input the street name and the house number separately. Or just treat street name and house number together as a single address item.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! My app is automatically creating package labels for DHL/DPD/Hermes... I don't have any influence of the street names. I get them via API from Amazon, Ebay.. If I can grab a number, everything is ok. If I can't get any number, the user have to manual look up for it.

Comment: That's what I want to say: You can treat the address line as one string and print it on the packet. A human, the delivery guy will read and interpret it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex is working for your example

```
^[ \-a-zA-Z.]+\s+(\d+(\s?\w$)?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/KumamP/4

The basic assumption is (like your samples suggest), that valid "street constellations" always start with a street name followed by the street/house number.

The next regex is also working if there is an entry like `Straße des 17. Juni 1`:

```
^[ \-0-9a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß.]+?\s+(\d+(\s?[a-zA-Z])?)\s*(?:$|\(|[A-Z]{2})
```

https://regex101.com/r/KumamP/5

But as the commentators already wrote, it is difficult to distinguish via an regular expression between numerical street name parts and the street number. Even more if you allow "unspecified" suffixes like `(Eingang Birkenstr.)` or `WH 5B 241` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing address lines is not trivial. Many countries have their own special rules and Germany and Austria are really tricky.

To understand better the examples you provided, there's one in special that shows the point:

"Eberhard-Leibnitz Str. 1 WH 5B 241"

The "WH" here stands for "Wohnung", but they usually use just "W" (and use some separator like "//"). So it would be more like:
"Eberhard-Leibnitz Str. 1 // W 5B 241"

It's also common to find "co" or "c/o" or "z. H" (abbreviation for "zu Händen von"). And anything that follows it, it's just the mailbox's name.

And last but not least, the address line could also contain the zip code + city name. Depends on the API you're interacting with, or if it's user input (it can get very wild then!).

So, to properly parse address lines, you should first normalize them, by removing that extra information. Then you can use a regex. Take a look at this gem: https://github.com/matiasalbarello/address_line_divider

Some good reads about the topic:

- https://www.german-way.com/germans-we-dont-need-apartment-numbers/
- https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/addressing-a-letter-in-germany
- http://interactive.zeit.de/strassennamen/